# Swift Firebase update old data - Real Time Database Triggers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the below image I have messages in my app, yet when a user say updates their profile image or name the data below becomes stale data. I have come across "Firebase Functions" and see that I can keep this data in-sync if I use Firebase Functions. Yet, only knowing Swift I am unsure how to implement Firebase Functions to keep my messages in-sync which the changing data in the user profiles. Can someone help me point in the right direction on how I implement this into my project? Haven't found any sample code in swift or any tutorials for that matter. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a great [codelab for cloud functions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0) to get you started with how to write them. And the answer is in your question: you have to write a function to locate and update your data.

Comment: When you say Firebase Functions, what do you mean exactly? Do you mean Cloud Functions? If so, those are not needed to keep data from being 'stale'. The question though is why would that data become stale? In other words, say a user "Lukas Bimba' changes his name to 'Mr. Lukas Bimba" - the data in Firebase at the */name* node would be *name: "Mr. Lukas Bimba"* which is current (not stale) data. So... how would it be stale?

Comment: @Jay The way it becomes stale data is that I save a users credentials into each message they send. So their profile image and name for example. If they update their profile image, the URL saved in the message becomes null so no image will be presented

Comment: Note: It's best practice here on SO to include your structures as TEXT, not images. That way, if we want to re-use them in an answer, we don't have to retype all of that. You can get to your structure as text through the Firebase Console->Three silly dots on the right->export JSON. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and the structure in the question, the reason the data is becoming stale is due to how the data is stored in Firebase.

One option is that when a message is sent, a node is written with the message and then a *reference* to the senders info. That keeps everything fresh and up-to-date at all times

So say we have a users node with users stored with the users UID as the key to each node

```
users
   uid_0
     user_name: "Peter"
     user_age:  "32"
     gender:    "Male"
     business_name: "Peter's Plumbing Place"
     url: "http:...."
     type: "Customer"
   uid_1
     user_name: "Ralph"
     user_age:  "47"
     gener:     "Male"
     business_name: "Ralph's Repair Room"
     url: "http:...."
     type: "Employee"
```

then we have messages

```
messages
   msg_0
     msg_text: "Here's a message!"
     from_uid: "uid_0"
     to_uid:   "uid_1"
     timestamp: "20180110"
```

Then, user uid_1 adds a query observer to the messages node for any messages where to_uid is uid_1 so they are notified of the incoming message. When they receive it, they will also know it was sent by uid_0 and can pull up their name, profile image, age etc.

That way, all data is kept in sync and current and no stale data exists.

This is a typical implementation of a structure for a messaging app.

Comment: I understand, yet this is a group messenger. So in my app I have 3 types of profiles, Customer, Employee, and Business Admin. I would have to make sure that the UID is going to the right query, either Customers, Employees, or Business Admin to pull their information. Maybe this is simpler than I think and I am just overthinking this

Comment: I completely understand the query, but I guess with how you are saying it I would have to write "if else" statements to tell the code which query/profile to pull the information from

Comment: @LukasBimba Nope. You know the uid of the user that sent the message so when the message node arrives on the client, grab the uid  and look it up. You don't need any if's elses or any other logic. I updated the users node in my answer. There's really no reason to 'know' what type of user sent it as if you know the users uid, you know everything about that user.

Comment: if I had a child "users" with everyone in it, it would be really easy I get that. I just added a picture with how my Database is setup.

Comment: I would need a query to access 3 different Childs and then make sure the UID is pulling information from the correct child

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah - with your current setup that makes it a LOT more complicated. I would suggest using the structure in my answer. In general you don't need to divide up your nodes like that unless you're denormalizing for certain types of queries. As you can see in my structure you can easily query for Customers or Employees etc. If you DO need them in their own nodes, just use the same process. have a */Employees* node with children that are references to the users node. */Employees/uid_1* and */Employees/uid_9* and then */Companies/uid_2* etc. You get the idea.

Comment: So I guess I just made it harder on myself separating the users like that?

Comment: Say I want to "transfer" all those users to a new child like what you have which is "users" is that possible or do I have to delete them and start from scratch

Comment: It would be relatively easy to craft an app to iterate over those nodes, update your structure and write them out to another node - like a /users node for example. Don't forget that if you need to know if they are a Customer, Employee etc, to add that as a child node to each when writing out. Not sure how important that is.